# Netbeans tld in jar not found

Tags: jsp, netbeans, jar, jsp-tags, tld

I added a tld file in my JAR library under

/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/tlds/example.tld"

and then in my webapp that includes the JAR lib I use the tld in my jsp like:

<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/tlds/example.tld" prefix="ex"%>
${ex: function(var)}

When I compile and run the webapp, everything works fine, but Netbeans gives me the following error.

File "/WEB-INF/tlds/example.tld" not found

Does anyone know how to fix the error or what is the correct way to use tlds from JAR libraries?

Comment: Is it only with the netbeans error,does the applications work fine(compile and execute) otherwise?

Comment: yes, everything works fine when compiled and run. Its only a problem in netbeans when coding.

Comment: SO the Netbeans IDE is not able to resolved thei stld which is available at run time to application.Try adding the '.tld' to the build path of the project

Comment: Sorry Shivam, what do you mean by adding the tld to the classpath. The JAR lib containing the .tld is already in the webapp's class path.

Comment: I ma not well versed with Netbeans,but there must be an option to configure build or class path to a project(similar to eclipse)